# Magento 2: Stop walk large collection

Tags: magento2, product-collection

I have a **walk** with large product collection. 
But I want to stop walk working. I don't have any idea for it.
Here is my code:

```
$this->_resourceIterator->walk(
        $productCollection->getSelect(),
        [[$this, 'callbackMappingProduct']],
        [
            'product' => $this->_productFactory->create()
        ]
);

public function callbackMappingProduct($args){
    /**
     * @var $product \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
     */
    if(true == $this->hasStop) {
          //Here I wanna stop my walk collection.
    }
}
```

Thank Any tips.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that you can do this natively.

You can create your custom iterator based on the `Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Iterator` and add some logic inside the `walk` function.

But another approach is to load bulk of data for large collection such as by 1000.

**Example of batch implementation for Indexes:**

You can also create your own class wich implements `Iterator` such as `Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\Fulltext\Action`

Then use :

```
   Magento\Framework\Indexer\SaveHandler\Batch $this->batch

   foreach ($this->batch->getItems($documents, $this->batchSize) as $batchDocuments) {
        // do ur stuff
    }
```